# Adding Local Include Directory to Luarocks install

Tags: lua, installation, luarocks

I have torch installed with prefix home/username/torch and am trying to run:

```
luarocks install trepl
```

Because I don't have sudo access to the cluster machine, I had to install readline (a dependancy of trepl) with prefix home/username/packages. I have added /home/username/packages/lib to my LD_LIBRARY_PATH, but I am running into an error that luarocks can't find readline.h (which is in packages/include)

Is there a way to specify an includepath to the luarocks install path

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Alright I just added the include and lib files to the torch/include and torch/lib and it built fine